# Django external service model integration patterns

Tags: django, api, django-models, integration

I have an app with the following models:

CustomUser
CustomGroup

When a CRUD action happens on one of the above models, i am required to call an external action with some custom logic.

```
Create an API create group -> API rename group -> API delete group.
```

When a create action completes a unique ID is returned which in turned needs to be saved against the model that initiated the call.

```
Model Create -> API create -> API return UUID -> Model Save
```

I believe using signals this would have the possibility to cause recursion.

Another scenario:

```
Model Update -> Has the name changed yes/no -> If yes update external API
```

So my question.. What would be a good design pattern to use to achieve this?

What level of separation should existing between the apps. 
Should the API calls exist isolated, and use signals to listen.

or

Should the CustomUser and CustomGroup methods actually have the logic within themselves.

Pro.
Context of an update.
Login in a single place

Example: user.update_api_details().

Con. 
Has knowledge of the external API
Can not be easily removed in the future.
Possible duplication of code if other parts of the system need to access functionality.

Thanks in advance,